# Cannot add users on Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

I recently purchased the Google Nexus 7 tablet running Android 4.2. [This link](http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2865483) describes how to manage multiple users on the same device. However the menu item "Users" does not exist on my table under the "Device" item.

The following menu items are visible:

- Sound
- Display
- Storage
- Battery
- Apps

Do I have to enable some other settings so that this item will become visible?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, have a look at this screen shot http://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3418647/Nexus_Daydream_1_thumb.png it shows where 'Users' should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot add users on Nexus 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37601/cannot-add-users-on-nexus-7)

Comment: Following the screenshot my device does not show the item "Users". It only shows: Sound, Display, Storage, Battery, Apps.

Comment: @t0mm13b 'Possible' duplicate? ;) I've already flagged the other one and this one contains more info so should probably keep this one open.

Comment: @Peanut yeah, I saw that, that you flagged the other one as a duplicate... ooops, cyclic duplicates... xD

Comment: @Robert can you confirm your android version number please? my nexus 7 runs 4.2.1 and shows users menu option. can you check for updates?

Comment: To the close-voters: The mentioned duplicate has just been closed in favour of this questions, so it's a bad idea to cross-close both of them ;)

Comment: It certainly shouldn't matter, but what flavor of device did you get? Did you get the 3G version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been solved. My device (3G) had Android 4.2 installed initially. However the multiple user functionality is only available with Android 4.2.1. My device didn't show the udpate. Today it did - no idea why - and now the item is visible.

Comment: Please accept this as the solution :)

Comment: Takes me another 17 hours to do so :-)